# Using Django CreateView how can I access the request.session.user variable?

Tags: django, crud

```
class ViewCreate(CreateView):
  model = view_C    
  author_name = self.request.user.username #this is the error
  author = get_user_model().objects.get(username=author_name).pk
  publish_date = datetime.date.today()

  initial={
'author':author,
'publish_date':publish_date,
}
```

author_name = self.request.user.username ...

> NameError: name 'self' is not defined

How do I access the request.user variable from within a subclass of CreateView?
I am trying to make use of a CreateView were the entries for author are automatically filled in using the session data and so don't have to be manaully entered.

Comment: With `request.user.username`, without `self`?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do this at that point. If you want to pass dynamic initial data based on the request, you need to do it by defining a `get_initial` method.

Note however the query you are doing is **completely pointless**. `request.user` is already an instance of the User model. There is no point getting the username from that object and then passing it into another query based on that username; you just get back the object you started with. Just use `request.user`.

```
class ViewCreate(CreateView):
    model = view_C    

    def get_initial(self):
        return {
             'author': self.request.user,
             'publish_date': datetime.date.today()
        }
```